# How to call generic method using type

Tags: c#

```
public void TestGeneric<TSource,TDestination>(IOverride<TSource,TDestination> override)
{
   do something
}

public void calling_method<TLValue, TRValue>(TLValue leftValue, TRValue rightValue)
{
     Type Source = leftValue.GetProperies().firstOrDefault();
     Type Destination = rightValue.GetProperies().firstOrDefault();
     var override = some method;
     TestGeneric<Source,Destination>(override);
}
```

I am having generic method which is having TSource and TDestination.
On the basis of this two it do some operations.

In calling method i can get the type which i have to pass.
I want do like

```
TestGeneric<Source,Destination>();
```

How to do that

Comment: You're looking for reflection. Suggested duplicate question will help. It is there right above your question.

Comment: I know its already asked question. Actually the problem is with passing parameter

Comment: What parameter? The example you posted doesn't have any parameter. Please explain what is your problem, simply saying problem isn't helpful.

Comment: Sorry i just update the question please find it

Comment: Second parameter of `Invoke` takes the parameters to the method You can do something like this `generic.Invoke(this, new object[]{ override });`

Comment: @Sriram the problem is with TestGeneric method. This method contain expression like override.Add(x=>x.someProperty, y=>y.SomePropert). If i change it to Array of object. It will not take expression

Comment: We have no idea what is `IOverride` or what you're trying to achieve. Please post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make the question clear. If the question is clear enough and a different one I'll reopen it.

Comment: IOverride is interface whose add method do mapping between source and destination. So as usual it need expression.

Comment: IOverride<TSource, TDestination> Add<TResult>(Expression<System.Func<TDestination, TResult>> destination, Expression<System.Func<TSource, TResult>> overrideFunction);  this is signature of Add